# Problem to replace the blank columns in big query with null

Tags: google-bigquery

I was expecting `Null_marker` to replace the blank STRING with `null` but, it did not work. Any suggestions, please?

tried using the  `--null_marker="null"`

```
$gcloud_dir/bq load $svc_ac --max_bad_records=10 --replace --source_format=CSV --null_marker="null" --field_delimiter=','    table     source
```

the empty stings did not get replaced with `NULL`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google Cloud Support here!

After reading through the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-cloud-storage-csv#csv-options), the description for the `--null_marker` flag states:

> Specifies a string that represents a null value in a CSV file. For example, if you specify "\N", BigQuery interprets "\N" as a null value when loading a CSV file. The default value is the empty string.

Therefore setting `null_marker=null` will not replace empty strings with `NULL`, it will only treat 'null' as a null value. At this point you should either:

- Replace empty strings before uploading the CSV file.
- Once you have uploaded the CSV file make a query using the [replace function](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/string_functions#replace).